# how activate buddy press on only one site in wordpress multisite?

Tags: wordpress, buddypress, multisite

I have a multisite wordpress setup, I have installed buddypress plugin for forum. I want to activate it on only one site instead of all sites. Please guide me how that is possible? Because I have an issue with users management, when I try to access "Pending" section in Users inside a site it gives error of "not sufficient permission". Please let me know how that is possible ?

thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In multisite setup choose you main site and than secondary site. After that you can choose in which site you want to install and configure buddypress.
For detail you can go there...
https://codex.buddypress.org/getting-started/installation-in-wordpress-multisite/

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have studied that and have put code "define( 'BP_ENABLE_MULTIBLOG ', true )" and "define ( 'BP_ROOT_BLOG', 2 )" in wp-config file. Problem is ... when user has been registered, a Pending link appears in Users page, when site administrator access it to approve user, it gives error "You have no sufficient permission to access this".